# File is in use by another process with SteamWriter

Tags: c#, file, streamreader

I'm coding in C# here and VS is saying the file is in use by another process when I try to read it with a `StreamReader` after creating it `File.Create(path)`.

Comment: Some code of your implementation would help us to provide better solution.

Comment: `File.Create` returns a stream. If you try to use another stream to access file that will happen. But since no example was provided we cannot tell for sure